# Regarding cutlery and industrial dishwashers

Tags: food-safety

This question I recently got a variety of cutlery for my school's cafeteria. However, after purchasing the cutlery, I realized that it may not be able to be washed by an industrial dish washer. These are for a relatively large school, and so, I assume, that an industrial washer is used to clean the countless spoons, forks, and knives. My only concern is that once they come into circulation, they may somehow deteriorate after being washed, or taint the food that is being eaten. Do I need to be careful as to what kinds of cutlery I buy, or are all metal cutlery okay to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dishwasher shouldn't be a concern - if anything it will be a little gentler on your cutlery.

Industrial washers work on a very short cycle (~2mins vs 2 hours).  Although "industrial" they actually clean a lot less than a domestic machine - home users expect  to put things in filthy and come out spotless and dry-ish. In a restaurant dishes are pre-cleaned.

That there's only about 20 seconds of cutlery sitting in salted water and steam(vs20-30min) makes a big difference.

Additionally, domestic powders often have abrasive agents, while this is uncommon in commercial kitchens where liquid-based systems are the norm.

The operating temperature is only about 5c higher so won't make much difference.

The main difference with restaurant grade cutlery is that it will be guaranteed to last a certain amount of time and manufacturers are careful about this because a restaurant is definitely going to look for their money back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no professional, but I have heard, mostly through family and friends, that anything with wood, because porous and can crack, warp and deform, should not be washed in a dishwasher.  My mother says no pots and pans or professional knives.  However, I got a nice set of pots and pans and they are holding up nicely.  I would put them in the dishwasher for several washes and just take a look.